# Why core::cmp::Ordering::cmp cast to i32 from for compare?

Tags: rust

THe `core::cmp::Ordering` type has `#[repr(u8)]`, but in [cmp method](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.60.0/library/core/src/cmp.rs#L871) we see the following code:

```rust
(*self as i32).cmp(&(*other as i32))
```

Why is the casting is not to `u8`?

Comment: Do you mean `i8` instead of `u8`?

Comment: yeah, sorry. I copied type from repr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the casting is not to u8?

The first reason would be that `Ordering`'s variants have the values -1, 0, and +1 so it would require an i8 to start with.

And although this was simply a replacement of `int` to `i32`, the reason why it's remained i32 rather than be narrowed to i8 is the [standard library integer usage guidelines](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22240):

> 1. Use unsigned values if the value should always be greater than or equal to zero, and signed values otherwise.
> 2. For indices, pointers, or other values which are tied to a data structure whose size is proportional to the size of memory, use usize or isize.
> 3. For cases where the acceptable domain of a value perfectly fits a fixed number of bits, use the appropriate fixed-size type. For example, a method like write_u16 would take a u16 argument.
> 4. Otherwise, use i32/u32 if the value has a narrow range and i64/u64 otherwise.

The examples specifically notes that this is a case were (3) doesn't actually apply, not with this example but with a fairly close one:

> The radix of an integer would use `u32`. You might expect `u8`, since a radix higher than 256 is not useful, but **the domain of useful radices is actually much smaller than `u8`, so using `u8` isn't providing a meaningful guarantee, and will simply increase friction**.

The exact same reasoning applies for ordering, it *probably* could have been an `i8` but there was no reason to break the guidelines, and that might have required additional compiler work (as some platforms have only a subset of all operations below 32 bits e.g. ARM). Though one drawback is a possible issue for platforms with 16 bits registers, I don't know if Rust supports or cares about those much (I know it supports pointers / addresses from 16 bits upwards, less sure for GPRs).